# indexing/slicing in numpy array to modify it

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, slice

I have a numpy array A and I want to modify values in it using a indexing list B. But the thing is in my slicing I can have an element of the array multiple times...
This example will explain better what I mean by that :

```
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(5) + 0.5
B = np.array([0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4])
print A[B]
```

returns as expected `[ 0.5 1.5 0.5 2.5 0.5 3.5 0.5 4.5]`.
However if I do that :

```
A[B] += 1.
print A
```

I was expecting to obtain `[ 4.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5]` as the first element is repeated 4 times in the indexing vector B, but it returns `[ 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5]`.
So how can I do what I actually wanted to do? (without using any loop as I'm using that on very large arrays)

Comment: Dont understand. Your expected result is `[ 4.5 2.5 3.5 4.5]` which has only 4 elements, and you have 5 indices in B. Why one element is missing?

Comment: I run your example on simple A (i.e. no random) to have some reproducibily of results: http://pastebin.com/mm2CcmK7  For me it seems to work ok, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: @Marcin A is not random in my case... it's arange(5) + 0.5 but anyway it works the same on your example and I was expecting to get `[15 23 34 45 56]` not `[12 23 34 45 56]` as the first element of A is repeated 4 times in the indexing list B, it should be submitted 4 times to the +1 operation... at least that's what I wanna do in the end. Any idea how?

Comment: Ah ok. Now i understand what you mean. Than check Jamie's anwser. It seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation why this happens is a little involved, but basically, "buffering ate your homework." There are a couple of ways around this issue of numpy ufuncs. The proper one, that will work with any operation is to use the corresponding ufunc's [`at` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html):

```
>>> A = np.arange(5) + 0.5
>>> B = np.array([0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4])
>>> np.add.at(A, B, 1)
>>> A
array([ 4.5,  2.5,  3.5,  4.5,  5.5])
```

This tends to be kind of slow, so for the fastest performance possible, and only for addition, you can use `np.bincount`:

```
>>> A = np.arange(5) + 0.5
>>> A += np.bincount(B) * 1  # replace the 1 with the number you want to add
>>> A
array([ 4.5,  2.5,  3.5,  4.5,  5.5])
```

**EDIT**

If what you want to add is an array of the same length as `B`, then the following, using `bincount`, is probably going to run faster than the first method:

```
>>> A = np.arange(5) + 0.5
>>> C = np.ones_like(B)  # They are all ones, but could be anything
>>> A += np.bincount(B, weights=C)
>>> A
array([ 4.5,  2.5,  3.5,  4.5,  5.5])
```

Comment: Thank you. That actually works perfectly but not exactly for what I wanted to do in the end... my example was to simple. If I have an other array C : `C = np.arange(8)`, what I wanna do (which is not working but so you can see the point) is something along those lines : `A[B]+=C`. So I'm not just adding a single value but an array of the same size as B. Am I clear or is it confusing?

Comment: sorry, your first solution is actually doing the job... as I wanted something efficient I skipped directly to the second one.

Comment: See my edit, it is likely faster than using `.at` for addition.

Comment: One issue that I still have is the method using `bincount` is that the indexing array (B) must contain at least once each of the indices of A otherwise you get a shape error `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together`. The `.at` method doesn't have this requirement.

Comment: You can use `bincount`'s `minlength`argument to fix that, so something like `np.bincount(B, weights=C, minlength=len(A))` should do it. But as you are noticing it gets hacky: unless this is a bottleneck for you, the proper thing to do is to use `.at`: it will likely get faster in future releases of numpy, it is a very recent addition.